# What is the probability that a majority vote gives the correct answer, given that we know the accuracy of each of the voters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say that we have 7 voters who are voting on a decision. Furthermore, we know that

- voter A makes the right decision with 10% probability.
- voter B makes the right decision with 20% probability.
- ...
- voter G makes the right decision with 70% probability.

What is the probability that a majority vote yields the correct decision? More generally, what is the probability that out of $n$ voters, each with accuracy $\alpha_i$, the majority vote yields the correct decision?

I can't seem to find a way to solve this other than doing a computer simulation.

Edit: approximations would help too. For example, how accurate is the estimate using the average accuracy of the voters.

$$
\bar{\alpha} := \left({\sum_i \alpha_i} \right) / n 
$$

$$
P[correct] \approx \sum_{k=n/2}^{n} {n \choose k} \bar{\alpha}^k (1-\bar{\alpha})^{n-k}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the voters cast their votes independently, you are looking at a [Poisson Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) (where what you call "accuracy" $\alpha_i$ is the parameter of the $i$-th Bernoulli):
$$
X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
where the $X_i$'s are independent (yet not necessarily identically distributed) Bernoulli distributions: $X_i \sim \operatorname{Bern}(\alpha_i)$.

Specifically, you are interested in the probability $\mathbb{P}\{X \geq \frac{n}{2}\}$.

For large $n$, standard tail bounds (e.g., [Chernoff or Hoeffding](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Readings/chernoffbounds.pdf)) may give you very sharp bounds on that quantity (depending on what $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$ is). For small $n$ (such as, in your question, $n=7$), you may as well compute the probability exactly using [the recursive formula for the probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).